# Eclipse debug can't find file

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I hope I capture this in the first pass:

I've just upgraded to Eclipse Juno.  I've got a brand new project, and I'm running into a debugging problem.

My structure is
    trunk, trunk/common, trunk/pctest

(With trunk hanging off of /home/tim/Documents/Customers/MyBusiness/Technical/)

I've got a program that's built in pctest/Debug, that has a ton of files in pctest, but which uses the file common/demodulate.cpp.  When I go to debug, and try to set a breakpoint in common/demodulate.cpp the breakpoint doesn't take, and I get the console message:

No source file named /home/tim/Documents/Customers/MyBusiness/Technical/trunk/common/demodulate.cpp

So I can't set a breakpoint in that file.  Yet, I can set a breakpoint in a file in trunk/pctest, then step into trunk/common/demodulate.cpp, and everything works just fine.

I really, really need to set breakpoints in that file!

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "Project - Path relative to source folder" to your "Source Lookup Path" in Preferences->Debug